# Checkbox toggle off and on, stays on after page reload

Tags: php, jquery, font-awesome

I am using a Font Awesome check-box on/off and the below script to toggle off and on when clicked.

This works fine if my links are #, but I recently changed my links to submit a form on a click of the check-box. This issue is once the page reloads, the checkbox goes back to the initial on state. I am not a Javascript pro and I am wondering if I can pass a variable to the script to set the state off/on?

```
<ul id="setting-cb">
<li class="wet-asphalt"><a href="<?php echo $my_url; ?>"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o wet-asphalt"></i></a>&nbsp; Checkbox 1</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $('#setting-cb li a').click(function(){
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('500');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There are many ways to do it, you could pass the variable as a parameter or use local storage or request the status via ajax... I could go on... I think the easiest for you would be to pass the value with the post and just catch it again.

Comment: You can just assign it to a javascript variable like so: var myValue = <?=json_encode($_SESSION['whateve_you_called_it'])?>;
Then you can do whatever you want with that variable. Add the class if you want, if(myValue == '1') $('#myButtonID').addClass('some_class');

Comment: I have the value of the checkbox in a hidden input (which I just added). I just do not know how to code the java-script to read this value and display the correct toggle icon.

Comment: If you have enough rep join me on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript and I will help you. If not join this one: http://www.chat27.co.za/27afrikaans.php

Comment: You really should be using a regular checkbox. You can still put your `<i>` element inside a label, and use CSS to hide the actual checkbox, but a checkbox has an inherit meaning to it vs a completely empty deprecated element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, because you already added the value to a hidden input you can simply catch it again using this:

```
class="<?=($_POST['your_checkbox_name'] == 'x')?'class_name':''?>"
```

Comment: Sorry, I was disconnected from the chat. I do not know what I was thinking. I do not even need the Javascript now, I will just set the class in PHP and return the class name. DUH! Thanks a lot, I should have figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform an Ajax call.
Here's an example:

JS:

```
$("#setting-cb li a").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('500');
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-square-o')
  $.ajax({
    url: '/destination.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      //your data Here 
    },
    success: function(response) {
      //Do something here...
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="setting-cb">
<li class="wet-asphalt"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-check-square-o wet-asphalt fa-square-o"></i></a>&nbsp; Checkbox 1</li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqrJae)